# CSS Transition not being executed

Tags: jquery, mobile, css, webkit, css-transitions

I am currently trying to animate two `div` elements in a carousel-type container. Here is the markup as it appears in the DOM:

```
<div id="transitioner" style="width: 2880px; height: 775px; left: -1440px; ">
    <div id="view1" class="view active" style="width: 1440px; height: 775px; ">
        <header>
            <h1>This is page 1</h1>
        </header>
        <article style="height: 699px; ">
            <p>Tap me anywhere to go to the next view</p>
        </article>
        <footer>
            <p>This is my footer</p>
        </footer>    
    </div>
    <div id="view2" class="view" style="width: 1440px; height: 775px; ">
        <header style="">
            <h1>This is page 2</h1>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS for the `#transitioner` element:

```
#transitioner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Finally, the JS:

```
function GotoView(view)
{
    var roller = $('<div id="transitioner" />');
    roller.width((viewport.width * 2)).height(viewport.height);
    var current = $('.view.active').clone(true, true);
    $('.view.active').remove();
    current.prependTo(roller);

    var new_view = view.clone(true, true);
    view.remove();
    new_view.appendTo(roller);

    roller.appendTo($('body'));
    $('body').addClass('transitioning');
    //window.setTimeout(function() { roller.css({ left: 0 - viewport.width }) }, 2000);
    roller.css({ left: 0 - viewport.width });
}
```

I update the left position of the containing `div` (i.e. `#transitioner`), but unless I put in a `setTimeout`, the CSS transition does not execute, rather the containing `div` simply 'jumps' to the desired new `left` offset.

I have put together a jsFiddle so you can see the symptoms > http://jsfiddle.net/XPUPQ/

My question is: what is this happening, and short of using the JS `setTimeout()` is there any way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to trigger a browser reflow

http://jsfiddle.net/XPUPQ/1/

You could do that with `$("body")[0].offsetWidth;` for example.

This is actually a legit technique that [twitter bootstrap uses](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-modal.js#L66) for example

Comment: Why do I say "for example" too much

Comment: Sounds better than 'perkele'.

Comment: Hehe thanks for the help, never come across this bug before and didn't know that caused a browser reflow. Any idea why we need to do this?

Comment: @BenM Because browsers optimize too much :P Maybe this helps though http://stackoverflow.com/a/6496557/995876